# How to trigger the Dropzone.js' default file upload input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'd like to know how to trigger the Dropzone.js' default file upload input?
It's not as simple like this:

```
window.dropCloud = = new Dropzone("#dropCloud", {...});
$(window.dropCloud.clickableElements[0]).trigger("click");
```

Now i don't have any ideas. Anyway the whole `#dropCloud` container is hidden, if it matters.

Answer (score 14):

This seems to work great for me

```
var dropZone = new Dropzone($("#yourdropzonedivthinger").get(0), {
BLAH BLAH BLAH drop zone init stuff
});

//Call this anywhere in your code to manually trigger the dropzone file dialog popup thinger

dropZone.hiddenFileInput.click();
```

Answer (score 14):

Simple. In version 4.0 you can do:

```
new Dropzone(".element", {
    clickable: '.myTrigger'
});

new Dropzone(".element", {
    clickable: ['.myTrigger', '.myOtherTrigger']
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and after quite a time of trying, i finally found a way how to add additional clickable areas to existing DropZone upload form.

Note: There must be at least one "original" clickable area attached initially by `clickable` parameter.

```
var DZ = Dropzone.forElement('.dropzone'); // Change selector to yours
var new_clickable = $('.new-clickable')[0]; // Change selector to yours
var new_listener = jQuery.extend({}, DZ.listeners[DZ.listeners.length - 1]);
new_listener.element = new_clickable;
DZ.clickableElements.push(new_clickable);
DZ.listeners.push(new_listener);
DZ.disable(); 
DZ.enable();
```

Basically what i do is

1. Add new clickable DOM element to `DZ.clickableElements`.
2. Clone last `DZ.listeners` array object.
3. Replace `element` property in `new_listener` object with ours.
4. Add both `new_clickable` and `new_listener` back to DZ.
5. Call `DZ.disable()` and `DZ.enable()` which reattaches all the event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Sigh... I think its the ugliest solution I've made... While init fn running.

```
this.clickableElements.push($("#anotherUploadBtn")[0]);
this.clickableElements.forEach(function(y){ ....
```

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#file-uploader").dropzone({
        url: "/upload/",
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 5,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*,.jpeg,.jpg',
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        clickable: ['#file-uploader *','#file-uploader'],
        init: function() {
            this.hiddenFileInput.click(); //opens the file select dialogue
        },
        accept: function(file, done) {
            // some code
            done();
        },
        success: function (file, responseText)
        {
            var responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseText);

            // some code
        },

});
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to the code.

Comment: i.e. you can put the code above into a function, when you call the function, the select file will open automatically with the initialization of dropzone. For example the user has to accept the upload rules before he/she can upload files, after he/she accepts the rules with click on the accept button you can call the function to initialize the dropzone and the select file window will open.